# Sync a small folder between my Mac and Pi 3

Tags: networking

I have a folder on my Mac that I always want synced with a folder on my Pi. I keep it synced to my laptop via MegaSync but my understanding is it doesn't like the Pi yet. 
Can someone recommend a method or sync software that will do this for me? I don't want to do it manually, and it does not have to sync when not on my network. I want it to sync to the SD card not a USB drive.

Thoughts?

Comment: You could `rsync` utility, run from a `cron`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a continuous synchronisation of files you can set up an open-source solution called [SyncThing](https://syncthing.net/).

For Mac it is available as a [Homebrew package](http://brewformulas.org/Syncthing).

On Raspbian you can install it using [these instructions](https://apt.syncthing.net).

It requires some initial configuration (you might want to limit it to your local network), but then you can stick to the web interface to set up shares and synchronisation schedule.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment, `rsync` will do this, and you would need to write a script to run it.

Unfortunately it depends WHAT you are trying to sync. `OS X` and `Raspbian` have different users which can make file access difficult, and `OS X` just plain refuses to save some directories (due to SIP). This may be more successful with a rsync daemon.